# React: Can you have a callback when a component receives a specific prop without using componentwillupdate?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback

I only want to call a callback when it gets a certain prop is updated.  My component gets updated props very frequently, so it'd be very inefficient to check for what props were updated in componentwillupdate.

Comment: Well, you have to check at some point, don't you? You could also check in the parent component which passes the prop, and call the callback from there.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can implement **componentWillReceiveProps** method and check if the current props is different than nextProps and update if new props recieves.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
   if(this.props.propsName !== nextProps.propsName){
      // do your update logic here
   }
}
```